# SeleniumJava : Deleting Unread Mails in Gmail

Tags: java, selenium

I am doing selenium practice and want to delete around 30K unread mails from my Gmail Inbox.I am Stuck on selecting the unread checkbox . tried lot of Locators and xpath But My xpath is selecting checkbox of All mail .

Can anyone suggest how to select checkbox of Unread Mails

PFB Java Selenium Code

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Unread_Gmail {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver;

driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1#identifier");

driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("*********@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("******");
driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();


Thread.sleep(3000);


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='G-tF']/div[1]/div")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=':z2']/div")).click();

//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='J-J5-Ji J-JN-M-I-Jm'][1]")).click();

//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='J-J5-Ji J-JN-M-I-Jm']")).click();
//driver.findElement(By.id("z2")).click();
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='J-N-Jz']")).click();
//driver.findElement(By.id("z2")).click();

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you familiar with [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/?hl=pl)? If you want to just practice locators and so on, locating the checkbox is the way to go, but in "real life" when you have to verify/test smtp servers, using API is the way to go. Every email (thread) has a [label](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels), calling messagesUnread will return unreaded messeges. You can also use a query, which both in API and UI:

```
in:inbox is:unread
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the locator for 'unread' dropdown option looks like this:

```
<div class="J-N" selector="unread" role="menuitem" id=":dz" style="user-select: none;">
    <div class="J-N-Jz" style="user-select: none;">Unread</div>
</div>
```

Looks like you need to look for element with class "J-N" and/or id ":dz".

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving the number of the element, like `1` and `2` and try clicking.

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@role='checkbox']")).get(1).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//JavaMail is an API which can be used to handle different operations in selenium.

 public static void main(String [] args){
        String to="";
        final String user=""; 
        final String password="xxxxx"; 
        
        //1) get the session object
        Properties properties = System.getProperties(); 
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "mail.javatpoint.com"); 
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthenticationgetPasswordAuthentication(){ 
                return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);
            }
        });
      
       // add code here to handle mails 
       }
```